Non-null assertions can only be used in TypeScript files.javascript
I've been working on this code base for the past month. And just yesterday, I started facing this problem on a few files. The code is supposed to change the div based on selected options. Here is the snippet that is showing the error (I've added comments to the specific lines that are showing the errors):


<script>
    function del(id) {
        //alert(id)
        $('#service_sales').load({
            !!json_encode(url('/invoice/remove')) !!
        } + '/' + id); // Shows error


    }
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#complete').on('click', '#complete', function() {
            $('#submit').click();

        });
        $('#service_id').on('change', function() {
            $('#complete').hide();
            $('#comment').hide();
            $('#tender').hide();
            var service_id = $('#service_id').val();
            //ajax
            $('#service_sales').load({
                !!json_encode(url('/invoice/sales')) !!
            } + '/' + service_id); // Shows error 
        });

        $('#patient_id').on('change', function() {
            var patient_id = $('#patient_id').val();
            $('#payment').show();
            $('#calculateBtn').show();
        });



        $('#calculate').click(function() {

            $('#tender').hide();
            $('#complete').hide();
            var cash = $('#cash').val();
            var discount = $('#discount').val();
            var sub_total = $('#sub_total').val();
            var tax = $('#tax_percent').val();

            if (sub_total.length) {

                if (cash > 0) {

                    var total = sub_total - discount;
                    var tax_amount = total * tax / 100;
                    var total_amount = total + tax_amount;

                    var tender_amount = cash - total_amount.toFixed();;

                    if (tender_amount < 0) {

                        $('#msg').show();
                        $("#msg").html("<div style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'><span class='btn-sm alert-danger'>Insufficient Balance...</span></div>");
                    } else {

                        $('#msg').hide();
                        $('#complete').show();
                        $('#comment').show();
                        $('#tender').html('<strong>Sub Total: Tk ' + sub_total + '</strong><br><strong>Discount: Tk ' + discount + '</strong><br><b>-----------------------------<b><br><strong>Total: Tk ' + total_amount.toFixed() + '</strong><br><strong>Cash: Tk ' + cash + '</strong><br><strong>Return: Tk ' + tender_amount.toFixed() + '</strong>');
                        $('#tender').show();
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#msg').show();
                    $("#msg").html("<div style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'><span class='btn-sm alert-danger'>Enter Cash Amount...</span></div>");
                }
            } else {
                $('#msg').show();
                $("#msg").html("<div style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'><span class='btn-sm alert-danger'>Please Select Doctor First...</span></div>");

            }

        });
    }); // Shows error

    function getDoctor() {
        var doctorName = $("#doctorName option:selected").text();
        $("#selectedDoctorName").val(doctorName);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



I'm getting different kinds of errors, such as:

Property assignment expected
Non-null assertions can only be used in TypeScript files.javascript
';' expected
Declaration or statement expected.javascript

I can also add VS Code screenshots if that's helpful.
There are other files too with the json_encode lines and they are also showing the same error. At first, I thought it was just a warning. However, this error is also affecting the project output, meaning, the intended code part is not working.
This is a PHP Laravel project. The only significant thing I remember doing is updating the Laravel from 5.4.* to 5.5.*, before which, it worked perfect. I'm still new so not sure how to handle this error. Or is there possibly another way to do what these lines of code are doing?
Thanks a lot. Here's the full file if you'd like to see: https://codeshare.io/3y1Vo6

Based on the docs load takes a string so it should be like this : $('#service_sales').load("{{ url('/invoice/sales') }}" + '/' + service_id);, tell me if this helps.

Why larevel tag?

Did you autoformat your code and turn statements like $('#service_sales').load({!! json_encode(url('/invoice/sales')) !!} + '/' + service_id); into the version with linebreaks that you currently have?

@Mohammadsiabbou Thanks a lot, man. That solved the problem.

@RobbyCornelissen It's PHP Intelliphense that does this automatically in VS Code.

@rustybladez i will put it as an answer and try to explain why. Glad it worked.

"The only significant thing I remember doing is updating the Laravel from 5.4.* to 5.5.*," - the last version of Laravel 5.4 has been published in August 2017, the last version of 5.5 in August 2020. Please keep in mind that the whole v5 branch of Laravel is highly outdated and should not have been in use for years. Also, is this a JS problem, an AJAX problem, a PHP problem, or a JSON problem?

The issue is here :
$('#service_sales').load({
  !!json_encode(url('/invoice/sales')) !!
} + '/' + service_id); // Shows error 

You have more than one problem here.

you are using an object as a parameter for a function that accepts a string.
you are not printing PHP code, you are writing it directly in JS which is invalid syntax.

The solution is
$('#service_sales').load("{{ url('/invoice/sales') }}" + '/' + service_id);

By using "{{ url('/invoice/sales') }}", the actual URL (the result of the PHP code) is printed. I am placing it inside double quotes so that JavaScript treats it as a string. This approach helps avoid “invalid syntax” issues, as JavaScript would otherwise interpret it as code.
